# How to avoid OR expansion?

Tags: oracle, database-performance, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

How to optimize the following query if the OR operator is used in a join condition to avoid the OR expansion in terms of SQL tuning?

```
SELECT t1.A, t2.B, t1.C, t1.D, t2.E 
   FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
   ON t1.A=t2.A OR t1.B=t2.C;
```

Comment: What is your problem with this query? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) the minimum you should post

Comment: Hi, here, as far as I know, the use of the OR operator is not a good thing in terms of the performance. So I wanted to learn how to avoid OR expansion in terms of SQL tuning.

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use? This is relevant here - check `select * from V$VERSION`

Comment: You should also learn to distinct between *using OR in a predicate* and the *OR expansion*. The former is done by you while writing the query, the latter is done by the Oracle Optimizer by *transforming the query* with the intention to help you, in case the *OR predicate* may cause performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Having OR condition will ignore using indexes. So once you have the following indexes -

```
t1 (A, B)
t2 (A, C)
```

You may try below query having UNION ALL clause -

```
SELECT t1.A, t2.B, t1.C, t1.D, t2.E 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.A=t2.A
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.A, t2.B, t1.C, t1.D, t2.E
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.B=t2.C;
```

This query will use index and might perform faster.

Comment: *Having OR condition will ignore using indexes* - do you have a source for that?

Comment: Transforming `or` into `union` is 'OR expansion', which is exactly what the OP wanted to avoid. https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion

Comment: a very rough rule of thumb is to replace an Or with a Union to avoid table scanning.

Comment: Well, whatever the reason, the OP wants to avoid it.

Comment: Your answert is **twice** wrong. First the proposed query returns *different* result (`UNION`should be used instead of `UNION ALL`). Secondly index is used to access *a small number of row based on access predicate*, here *all rows are joined*, so no index will be used in neither variant. (ignoring the option of the *fast full index scan*).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`NO_EXPAND` hint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D4C251F0-B3A3-4D7E-843E-3491608D48DB) to prevent OR-expansion:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_EXPAND */ t1.A, t2.B, t1.C, t1.D, t2.E 
   FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
   ON t1.A=t2.A OR t1.B=t2.C;
```

However, the chances are very small that the above hint will improve your query performance. There is no rule that says OR-expansion is a bad thing. Telling the Oracle optimizer precisely how to do its job is usually a bad idea. Ideally, you want to create useful information by gathering statistics, and let the optimizer do its job.